# When I am using CancellationTokenSource, do I pass around a reference to that or to the CancellationTokenSource.Token?

Tags: c#

Here is the code I am using.  What I want is for when a screen appears that code inside a while loop runs. When the screen Disappears then I need it to stop. Can someone give me advice on whether I am using the CancellationTokenSource correctly for this functionality. Also do I need to do the actions of both .Dispose() and then setting to null like I am doing here?

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
   cts1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
   await GetWork(cts1.Token);
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
   cts1.Cancel();
   base.OnDisappearing();
}

public async Task GetWork(CancellationToken ct)
{
      while (true)
      {
         if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            break;
         // do work
      }
}
```

Comment: Based on official .NET APIs you give the token, not the source

Comment: Yes that's what I am noticing but the application has been running for some time now without problems so I am looking for some advice here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rule of thumb is:

- Any code that needs to cancel the token should have access to the `CancellationTokenSource`
- Any code that needs to *respond* to cancellation should have access to the `CancellationToken`

That's why most API code just accepts a `CancellationToken` - it doesn't need to actively cancel the token itself, it just needs to notice when it's been cancelled by something else.

So in your case, `OnDisappearing` needs access to the `CancellationTokenSource`, but `GetWork` probably only needs a `CancellationToken`. (It's not clear to me why you're calling `Cancel` within the catch block, but you probably don't need to.)

Comment: Hi Jon,  Could you perhaps give an example with my code being copied / pasted into the answer that shows how you would code this up?  Good point about the cancel in the catch block btw. Thanks

Comment: @Alan2: I'm not sure what you're looking for - you only need to pass the `CancellationToken` into `GetWork` (i.e. call `GetWork(cts1.Token)`... have you *tried* doing that?

Comment: What's confusing me is should I then have ct.IsCancellationRequested where ct is the token and then what about what I do in the catch where I do the cts.Dispose? If I just pass in the ct then I won't have access to the cts to do a .Dispose on it.  Sorry but I am a bit confused here.

Comment: @Alan2: You don't need to dispose it, basically. It's fine not to dispose of a `CancellationTokenSource`, in general - but even if you *did* want to dispose it, you're already disposing of it in `OnDisappearing`. Why would you want to call `Dispose` twice? (There's also no point in setting the parameter to null...)

Comment: I edited the code in the question. Can you confirm if that's the way you think I should be doing it? I also removed the try so hopefully that's okay now.

Comment: @Alan2: Yes, that should work fine. If you're passing the token into any other async methods, you'd probably want to change to go back to including a `catch` block and just call `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`, as cancellation more *typically* throws an exception than just stopping a loop - but what you've got should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

All official async .NET APIs accept a `CancellationToken` and also the [guidelines](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrewarnottms/2014/03/19/recommended-patterns-for-cancellationtoken/) define how it should be used. The source is just a source for the caller to handle the token.

The documentation for [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=netframework-4.7.2) also explains the use pattern:

- Instantiate a CancellationTokenSource object, which manages and sends cancellation notification to the individual cancellation tokens.
- Pass the token returned by the CancellationTokenSource.Token property to each task or thread that listens for cancellation.
- Call the CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested method from operations that receive the cancellation token. Provide a mechanism for each task or thread to respond to a cancellation request. Whether you choose to cancel an operation, and exactly how you do it, depends on your application logic.
- Call the CancellationTokenSource.Cancel method to provide notification of cancellation. This sets the CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested property on every copy of the cancellation token to true.
- Call the Dispose method when you are finished with the CancellationTokenSource object.

Comment: Can you perhaps give some code in the example.  Might just be a copy paste of my code with the correction made so others can follow it.  Thanks

Comment: @Alan2 Added a link and explanation from Microsoft’s documentation

Comment: Thanks Sami, Could you add your suggestions to my code and make that part of the answer to.  That way it will be more clear.